# How to assign attributes to a vertex

Tags: r, attributes, igraph

I have a graph, e.g.

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.ring(10)
V(g1)$name <- letters[1:10]
```

I want to add different color attributes to vertices based on condition. For example, add color 'red' when vertex names are `%in% letters[c(3,5,8)]`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
V(g1)$color <- ifelse(V(g1)$name %in% letters[c(3,5,8)], "Red", "Blue")
plot(g1)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Yes this is exactly I want. TKS